# psycopg2 connect to postgres using custom websocket

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, websocket, psycopg2

I have a postgres cluster deployed in kubernetes and I am doing port-forwarding so that I can access the pod from outside the kubernetes cluster

```
from kubernetes.stream import portforward

pf = portforward(
  self.core_v_api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward,
  name, namespace,
  ports=str(ports),
)
return pf
```

This returns me a `websocket`:

```
<websocket._core.WebSocket object at 0x7ff628132c50>
```

I have to use this WebSocket to connect with the Postgres, is there a way I can use `psycopg2` with a custom WebSocket or any other way?

Comment: No, `psycopg2` needs to connect to the database server not the Web server.

Comment: I understand that, but for the network communication it's going to use the socket connection, and the question is can I pass my own socket instead of `psycopg2` creating one for connecting to the database.

Comment: `psycopg2` uses [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) and I don't see that it knows anything about WebSockets on its own.  I did run across this [Postgres/WebSocket demo](https://gist.github.com/drocco007/6e44ac1a581546c16e67) which has a link to another post. Does not make sense to me, but you might get some ideas.